# ideal way of creating NSString

Tags: ios, objective-c

Is it really required to create the string using below mention format when ARC is enabled

```
NSString *string =[[NSString alloc]init];
          string =@"Hello";
```

or is it ideal to use use below mentioned format

1. `NSString *theString = @"hello";`
2. `NSString *string1 = [NSString stringWithString:@"hello"];`

Comment: Doing the initialization before assignment is, er, "foolish".  Similarly, using `[NSString stringWithString:@"hello"]` is "foolish", except in very limited circumstances.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is never require to alloc init an `NSString` (or at least it's basically useless), particularly if you're then going to assign the variable to another string immediately. That just results in the first string getting destroyed.

Option 1) is good.

Option 2) is bad, you already have a string literal so you don't need to alloc unit another string instance.

Answer (score 3):

```
 NSString *string =[[NSString alloc]init]; 
 string =@"Hello";
```

That is totally stupid, for a string or anything else. You are creating a string in the first line and throwing it away in the second line. If you weren't using ARC this would be a leak.

Comment: you are right of course but I  think a little less attitude would be cool :)

Comment: Neither rude nor attitude, but pedagogically strategic. It _is_ a stupid thing to do, I am telling Nextric strongly not to do it, and I am clearly right to emphasize this - since I see people on StackOverflow making this mistake very often. It is in fact one of the Top Ten iOS Programming Mistakes.

Comment: I've use "stupid" to refer to that "pattern" several times.  It exhibits total ignorance of the difference between defining a pointer, setting it's value, and modifying the thing pointed to.  These are critical distinctions whenever anyone is doing OO programming, and one should not be programming in Objective-C, in particular, if they do not understand the distinctions.

Answer (score 1):

```
NSString *string =[[NSString alloc]init];
string =@"Hello";
```

There are two problems with the code above:

1. You're creating a new, empty string and assigning it to `string`, and then assigning a *different* string object to `string`. The second line doesn't change the *contents* of the string you created on the first line; it changes what `string` points to. Therefore, the only useful effect of the fist line is that it declares the `string` variable.
2. `NSString` is a class that represents immutable strings. That is, once you create an instance of `NSString` you can't change it. You have to provide the content of an immutable object when you create it. So when you say `[[NSString alloc] init]`, you get an empty string that can never become non-empty, and judging by what you're trying to do that's not what you want.

So, you need to decide whether you want an immutable string that contains "Hello" or a mutable string that you can change later. In the former case you could do it like this:

```
NSString *string = @"Hello";
```

or like:

```
NSString *string = [NSString stringWithString:@"Hello"];
```

or like:

```
NSString *string = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"Hello"];
```

Any of those are valid, but the first is the shortest and clearest. If you want a mutable string, you can say:

```
NSMutableString *string = [NSMutableString string];
[string setString:@"Hello"];
```

A shorter way to do the same thing is:

```
NSMutableString *string = [@"Hello" mutableCopy];
```